# How to debug a key-binding/expansion in emacs? Specifically `<s` + `tab` in org-mode

Tags: debugging, emacs, org-mode

So I must have broken something in my configuration (not all that hard to do).  Now when I go to expand a code block in org-mode via `<s`+`tab` it no long expands.  I don't run yassnippet or something like that, which I thought might be interfering with org-mode.  However this really isn't strictly a keybinding and I think is just built into org-mode.

Not sure how to debug this and figure out what I must have misconfigured.  What is the way to go about debugging broken org-mode script block expansions?

Comment: if you recently upgraded, org now uses `C-c C-,` to expand -- broke my config as well

Comment: Doing `(require 'org-tempo)` should bring the `easy-template` keybindings back. You'll need to install `tempo` of course: `org-tempo` depends on it (correction: I think it comes with Emacs). But `C-c C-,` ([assuming you can type it](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55134/org-priority-and-org-insert-structure-template-key-binding-clash/55141#55141)) has advantages: e.g. it allows you to wrap the markers around a region.

Comment: @NickD That's what I found as well.  I'd accept that as an answer if you wanted to post that answer.